# Generating a new CSR with openssl

Tags: openssl, debian, ssl-certificate, csr

OpenSSL - Debian - Apache

I've got to generate a new CSR to install a new SSL Certificate.
I know I can generate one off of the existing Private Key, but assume it's a good idea to generate a new one of those at the same time (?), if I do that I don't want to have to input a password every time Apache starts.

If my key is currently domain.com.key and CSR domain.csr, then running the following would replace both and give me what I need?

```
 openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout domain.com.key -out domain.csr
```

Since I have to pass the CSR to someone else in the org who deals with obtaining the certificates, then this would mean they would be inaccurate whilst I waited for the certificate to reach me (?) - so if I called them different filenames at this stage of the generation, what "gotchas" would I have look out for when I did come to install the certificate? Any "standard" places where a different filename would be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The filenames are irrelevant except for software to find the file.  You can move the new key in place when you have received the certificate.